# Nservicebus Sequence

Tags: wcf, msmq, nservicebus, nservicebus5

We have a requirement for all our messages to be processed in the order of arrival to MSMQ.

We will be exposing a WCF service to the clients, and this WCF service will post the messages using NServiceBus (Sendonly Bus) to MSMQ.

We are going to develop a windows service(MessageHandler), which will use Nservicebus to read the message from MSMQ and save it to the database. Our database will not be available for few hours everyday.

During the db downtime we expect that the process to retry the first message in MSMQ and halt processing other messages until the database is up. Once the database is up we want NServicebus to process in the order the message is sent.

Will setting up  MaximumConcurrencyLevel="1" MaximumMessageThroughputPerSecond="1" helps in this scenario?

What is the best way using NServiceBus to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

> We have a requirement for all our messages to be processed in the
>   order of arrival to MSMQ.

See the answer to this question [How to handle message order in nservicebus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668233), and also this post [here](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/nservicebus-in-order-message-processing).

I am in agreement that while in-order delivery is possible, it is much better to design your system such that order does not matter. The linked article outlines the following soltuion:

> - Add a sequence number to all messages
> - in the receiver check the sequence number is the last seen number + 1 if not throw an out of sequence exception
> - Enable second level retries (so if they are out of order they will try again later hopefully after the correct message was received)

However, in the interest of anwering your specific question:

> Will setting up MaximumConcurrencyLevel="1"
>   MaximumMessageThroughputPerSecond="1" helps in this scenario?

Not really.

Whenever you have a requirement for ordered delivery, the fundamental laws of logic dictate that somewhere along your message processing pipeline you must have a single-threaded process in order to guarantee in-order delivery.

Where this happens is up to you (check out the [resequencer pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Resequencer.html)), but you could certainly throttle the NserviceBus handler to a single thread (I don't think you need to set the MaximumMessageThroughputPerSecond to make it single threaded though).

However, even if you did this, and even if you used transactional queues, you could still not guarantee that each message would be dequeued and processed to the database in order, because if there are any permanent failures on any of the messages they will be removed from the queue and the next message processed.

> During the db downtime we expect that the process to retry the first
>   message in MSMQ and halt processing other messages until the database
>   is up. Once the database is up we want NServicebus to process in the
>   order the message is sent.

This is not recommended. The second level retry functionality in NServiceBus is designed to handle unexpected and short-term outages, not planned and long-term outages.

For starters, when your NServiceBus message handler endpoint tries to process a message in it's input queue and finds the database unavailable, it will implement it's 2nd level retry policy, which by default will attempt the dequeue 5 times with increasing infrequency, and then fail permanently, sticking the failed message in it's error queue. It will then move onto the next message in the input queue.

While this doesn't violate your in-order delivery requirement on its own, it will make life very difficult for two reasons:

1. The permanently failed messages will need to be re-processed with priority once the database becomes available again, and
2. there will be a ton of unwanted failure logging, which will obfuscate any genuine handling errors.

If you have a regular planned outages which you know about in advance, then the simplest way to deal with them is to implement a service window, which another term for a schedule.

However, Windows services manager does not support the concept of service windows, so you would have to use a scheduled task to stop then start your service, or look at other options such as [hangfire](http://hangfire.io/), [quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) or some other [cron-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron) library.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom. This was really useful.

Answer (score 1):

It kinds of depends why you need the messages to arrive in order. If it's like you first receive an `Order` message and then various `OrderLine` messages that all belong to a certain order, there are multiple possibilities.

One is to just accept that there can be `OrderLine` messages without an `Order`. The `Order` will come in later anyway. Eventual Consistency.

Another one is to collect messages (and possible state) in an NServiceBus Saga. When normally `MessageA` needs to arrive first, only to receive `MessageB` and `MessageC` later, give all three messages the ability to start the saga. All three messages need to have something that ties them together, like a unique GUID. Then the saga will make sure it collects them properly and when all messages have arrived, perhaps store its final state and mark the saga as completed.

Another option is to just persist all messages directly into the database and have something else figure out what belongs to what. This is a scenario useful for a data warehouse where the data just needs to be collected, no matter what. Some data might not be 100% accurate (or consistent) but that's okay.

Asynchronous messaging makes it hard to process them 100% in order, especially when the client calling the WCF is making mistakes and/or sending them out of order. It wouldn't be the first time I had such a requirement and out-of-order messages.